# How to get enum description in mybatis when serializing to JSON String

Tags: java, enums, mybatis

### Question is how to get enum description in mybatis when serializing to JSON String

mybatis works fine to get an enum property and it also works fine to get description value by Model.DocFlowEnum.getStateName()

**But how to get the description value `this is a draft` instead of ordinary value `Draft` when serializing to JSON String?**

Because it is a list, I don’t want to loop to manually set the descrition value

### DocFlowEnum, DocFlowEnumTypeHandler ,Model

#### Here is the enum with description

```java
public enum DocFlowEnum{

    Draft(0, "this is a draft"),

    ToProcess(1, "this is to process"),

    InProcess(2, "this is in process"),

    private static final Map<Integer, DocFlowEnum> byState = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        for (DocFlowEnum e : DocFlowEnum.values()) {
            if (byState.put(e.getState(), e) != null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("duplicate state: " + e.getState());
            }
        }
    }

    public static DocFlowEnum getByState(Integer state) {
        return byState.get(state);
    }

    // original code follows
    private final String stateName;

    private final Integer state;

    DocFlowEnum(Integer state, String stateName) {
        this.state = state;
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }

    public Integer getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }
}
```

#### here is the TypeHandler for mybatis

```java
@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.INTEGER)
@MappedTypes(value = DocFlowEnum.class)
public class DocFlowEnumTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<DocFlowEnum> {
    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, int i, DocFlowEnum userStateEnum, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        preparedStatement.setInt(i,userStateEnum.getState());
    }

    @Override
    public DocFlowEnum getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, String s) throws SQLException {
        int code =resultSet.getInt(s);
        if(code>=0&&code<=5){
            return DocFlowEnum.getByState(code);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DocFlowEnum getNullableResult(ResultSet resultSet, int i) throws SQLException {
        int code = resultSet.getInt(i);
        if(code>=0&&code<=5){
            return DocFlowEnum.getByState(code);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public DocFlowEnum getNullableResult(CallableStatement callableStatement, int i) throws SQLException {
        int code = callableStatement.getInt(i);
        if(code>=0&&code<=5){
            return DocFlowEnum.getByState(code);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Here is the Model

```java
@Data
public class Document{

    private DocFlowEnum stateEnum;

}
```

### Thank you so much to everyone who helped.

Answer (score 0):

OK, after 30minutes, I find the solution. so easy.

```java
    @JsonValue
    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }
```

Maybe this can help others.